# Error en flutter al iniciar proyecto

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

Tengo un error al iniciar un proyecto con flutter. Me sale lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo instalado DART, FLUTTER, las extensiones en visual studio. He reinstalado visual studio code limpio y al crear el proyecto otra vez (el que viene por defecto) me siguen danddo los mismos errores y no puedo debugear.

Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Primero valida si tienes errores de instalación con flutter, con el comando: flutter doctor -v.

Luego también valida si el path del flutter sdk tiene la ruta correcta. Esto lo puedes validar:

- En android studio --> preferences --> Plugins y le asignas la ruta en la propiedad de flutter
- En el archivo de .bash_profile colocas:

  PATH="/tu_ruta/flutter/bin:${PATH}"

  export PATH